# Baire Category Theorem: What should we really prove there?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, baire-category

I am reading about the Baire Category Theorem in Jech's [book](http://logic.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/Jech,+T.+J.+(2003).+Set+Theory+(The+3rd+millennium+ed.).pdf) on set theory.

**4.8: Baire Category Theorem**: Let $D_0,D_1,\dots,D_n,\dots$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, be open dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Then the intersection, $D=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n\ $ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

My question:

> Isn't any dense open set in $\mathbb{R}$ equal to $\mathbb{R}$?
> I mean, that $U$ is dense means that, for every open interval $(a,b)$, $U\cap(a,b)\neq\emptyset$. Furthermore, that $U$ is open means that every point is an interior point. So, isn't $U$ just a union of open intervals which equals $\mathbb{R}$?
> I can't figure out what I am missing here..

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: the irrationals are dense in the reals but are not equal to the reals.  Does that help you a little?

Comment: But the set of rationals is not open in R..

Comment: get it now... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Enumerate the rational numbers $q_1, q_2, q_3, \dots$. Then place an open interval with length $1/2^n$ centered at $q_n$. The union of these intervals is open and dense, yet has finite total measure (length) and thus cannot be all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: got it! Thanks!!

Comment: @Shir Even simpler: $\mathbb R\setminus\{a\}$ is dense for any $a$. This is the Hint the first comment on the post was aiming at.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: That example is far simpler than mine! +1

Comment: Cool!! Thanks!!!

Comment: This answer just blew my mind! Never thought of that before.